# Php Dom Parser error Uncaught SyntaxError

Tags: php, parsing, dom

So I have been trying to get this to work and it is working. I tried it on Imgur but I just can't get it to work on this website... I need help.

```
<?php   
# create and load the HTML
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html = file_get_html('https://www.ivory.co.il/');

foreach($html->find('a') as $e) 
    echo $e->href . '<br>';

    foreach($html->find('img') as $e)
    echo $e->src . '<br>';

echo $html->save();
?>
```

This is what I get in the console.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me. Did you tried with different URL, just for croscheck the functionality?

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

That website is quite tricky! If you look carefully you'll notice that upon first visit it sets a cookie and redirects you back to the home page. By default `simple_html_dom` doesn't remember cookies and doesn't follow redirects (so you can never scrape the actual website data).

To fix it you need to use CURL and set it to:

- Allow redirects
- To store cookies
- To send cookies back with each request.

I've adapted your code:

```
<?php   
# create and load the HTML
include('simple_html_dom.php');

// Initialize CURL
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.ivory.co.il/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);

// This tells CURL to follow any redirects
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

// Don't verify the SSL certificate (can be removed if website has valid cert)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

// Here you tell CURL to save all cookies to the file cookiejar.txt
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookiejar.txt');

// Here you tell CURL to send the stored cookies with each request you make
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookiejar.txt');

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Load the HTML source code from a string
$html = str_get_html($data);

// Your code goes here!
foreach($html->find('a') as $e){
    echo $e->href . '<br>';
}

foreach($html->find('img') as $e){
    echo $e->src . '<br>';
}
```

Hope that helps you!